# How to connect MQTT broker to node js application

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am absolutely new to MQTT and tried to connect to mqtt using my node application. I tried a few codes that I found online but none seem to work.
I must be doing something wrong but I really can't figure what. A little help would be appreciated.

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mqtt = require('mqtt');


const options={
    clientId:"mqttjs_"+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,8),
    username:"rj******",
    password:"iCfs*******",
    clean:true,
    keepalive: 60,
    reconnectPeriod: 1000,
    protocolVersion: 3,
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    encoding:'utf-8'
};
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://farmer.cloudmqtt.com',options)

client.on("connect",function(){ 
    console.log("connected");
});
```

Expected this code to console log connected after Server running but it did not do so. Please help

Comment: It will definitely not connect without passing the `options` object. Edit the question to put it back. Also remove all the express code from the example as it has nothing to do with the problem. I suggest you add a `client.on('error`,...)` callback so you can see what errors are being produced.

Comment: You haven't added the `client.on('error', function(err){})` callback that will show you why it's not connecting https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#event-error